Using from tensorflow.keras.utils import pad_sequences results in IndexError: too many indices for array
I'm doing use pad_sequences().
Here's my code:
from tensorflow.keras.utils import pad_sequences
input_x[i] = pad_sequences(x00_1[i], padding='post', maxlen=128,dtype='float32')

x00_1.shape = ( 1, 389, 39 )
but I got an error IndexError: too many indices for array.
How can I fix it?
My version:
Python 3.6
Tensorflow 1.14.0
Keras2.3.1


It is likely due to the fact that you're trying to apply pad_sequences to an element of 'x00_1[i]' that is not compatible with the expected input shape for pad_sequences.
'x00_1[i]' is a 3-D array 
pad_sequences() is typically used on a list of sequences, where each sequence is a 1D array or list of integers or floats. It is meant to be of uniform length.
You are trying to index x00_1 with input_x[i] = pad_sequences(). Since x00_1 is a 3D array, x00_1[i] will be a 2D array, which may not be the expected input for pad_sequences.

To fix this:


If you want to pad the second dimension, you need to loop through the first dimension and apply pad_sequences on each list of sequences .

You should convert the relevant slice of the array into a list of sequences before applying pad_sequences.



You can code it using the below steps:


Use a loop to convert the 2D array of shape (389, 39) into a list of 1D arrays (each of length 39)
Apply pad_sequences
Convert the list of padded sequences back into a NumPy array

